# How to copy from one branch to another - Files going to master?

Tags: git, copy, branch

I am trying to add some files from another branch, but they are being put onto master.

How can I copy files from one branch to another?

I tried a good ole' fashioned `cp`: switch to source branch, copy to /tmp, switch to the target branch, and copy. Tried to add...  but the copied files are on `master` ?!

```
cd cheese_repo
git branch cheddar
ls
    react
cp -r react /tmp

git branch swiss
cp -r /tmp/react .
ls
    react
git branch
    * swiss
cd react
git branch
    * master
```

Why are these files now in master? I was in the `swiss` branch when I copied them.

This got me into some warm water... I did a `commit` and `push` without realizing that I was on `master`. Committing directly to `master` is `no-no` where I work.

How can I get my `react` files into the `swiss` branch for commit and push? Tyvm Keith :^)

Answer (score 2):

The way to bring over a file *as is* from another branch is with checkout:

```
git checkout other-branch -- some-file
```

That will put the file as it in on the other branch on the working tree *and* the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch
    * swiss
cd react
git branch
    * master
```

It seems `react/` is a submodule, i.e. it has its own directory `.git/`, its own independent history (commits), its own branches.

Answer (score 0):

From your below output, its seems that react folder is a repository in itself.

```
git branch
* swiss
cd react
    git branch
    * master
```

You can check it by doing `git remote -v` from both folders i.e. cheese_repo and react. It will give you the origin repo links.

From your question, you want to have your folder react in the swiss branch of your cheese_repo. You can do add and push, once you are in swiss branch.

```
git branch
* swiss
git add react
git commit -m '<your commit msg>'
git push origin swiss
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for posterity, git thought that the directory was part of a submodule.

I found this by `cd`'ing into the directory and doing a `git add` on a specific file. It threw this error:

```
fatal: Path 'web/react/package.json is in submodule 'web/react'
```

The solution was this:

1. rm -rf `.git` folder in directory
2. run `git rm --cached path_to_submodule` (no trailing slash)

Then I was able to:

3. `git add --all react`
4. `git status`
5. `git commit -m "My awesome UI"`
6. `git push`

Voila! Files in Bitbucket on the correct branch.

Reference:

- https://gist.github.com/kyleturner/1563153